# An android tablet nexus 7(Lollipop) can be used as a Bluetooth headset for another device?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, headset

What I want to do is develop an application on Android tablet nexus 7 which will act as a bluetooth headset, so it can connect to my android device by bluetooth. When I try to call somebody, I can use my phone to dial him, and my application will forward the voice through bluetooth to my Android tablet, and one other application running on Android tablet will get the voice data.